# Closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(-2^{-2^{-n}}\right)}{\sqrt{2^n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math, closed-form, polylogarithm

Let
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(-2^{-2^{-n}}\right)}{\sqrt{2^n}},\tag1$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_a(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html). For $a=1/2$ it can be represented as
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(z)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{\sqrt k}\tag2\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac z{\sqrt{\pi\,x}\ \left(e^x-z\right)}\,dx.\tag3\end{align}$$

---

How to find a closed-form expression for $S$?

Comment: Why do you need a closed form for $S$? Do you expect it to have closed form? What is the motivation for your question?

Comment: It is a contest problem. There is a closed form, but I do not know it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Result**:
$$\boxed{\; S=\sqrt{2}\,\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(\frac14\right)-\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{\ln 2}}\;}\tag{1}$$

---

**Derivation**:

1. Let us denote
   $$a_n=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(-2^{-2^{-n}}\right)}{2^{n/2}},
   \qquad 
   b_n=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(2^{-2^{-n}}\right)}{2^{n/2}}.$$
   These quantities satisfy the recurrence relation
   $$a_n+b_n=b_{n-1},\tag{2}$$
   which follows from the [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/17/02/01/02/0001/)
   $$\sqrt{2}\,\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(z^2\right)=
   \operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(z\right)+\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}\left(-z\right).$$
2. The relation (2) implies that
   $$b_N+\sum_{n=0}^Na_n=b_{-1},$$
   and therefore our series telescopes:
   $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=b_{-1}-b_{\infty}.\tag{3}$$
3. The polylogarithm asymptotics
   $$\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(x)\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\quad \text{as}\;\;
   x\rightarrow 1^-,$$
   implies that $\displaystyle b_{\infty}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln 2}}$. Being combined with (3), this finally gives the above answer (which is further confirmed numerically).